# Swift : Bridging-Header の import で file not found が発生してしまう

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

当方 iOS 開発初心者のため、初歩的な質問でしたら申し訳ありません…

Swift の iOS アプリを作成しており、円グラフの描画のために CorePlot を使用しようとしております。 こちらのブログ　「 [Using CorePlot with Swift in iOS](http://blog.alwold.com/2014/08/07/using-coreplot-with-swift-in-ios/) 」 を参考に下記の手順を試しました。

---

1. CorePlot を `pod install`
2. Bridging-Header ファイルを作成 （※以下、ヘッダファイル）
3. ヘッダファイル内で `CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h` を import
4. アプリターゲットの Objective-C Bridging-Header にヘッダファイルを登録

---

ですが、下記のように import を行う際にエラーが発生してしまいます。

[image: import error]

実際にファイルの存在を確認すると、 `Users/USER_NAME/Document/workspace/PROJECT_NAME/Pods/CorePlot/framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h` に存在しておりました。

なのでおそらくパスの通し方が悪いのかなと思い、こちらの Qiita 記事　「[Swift：SwiftからObjectiveCのコードが参照できないときのチェックポイントメモ](http://qiita.com/mokemokechicken/items/6716193cfcbd0a4d8b84)」 を参考に修正してみましたが、以前変わらないままです。 試したのは *"Bridging-Header内のimportファイルがテストプロジェクトからfile not foundになる"* の部分です。

こちら、どのように対処すればよろしいでしょうか。何か追記すべき情報がある場合は、お手数ですがコメントいただけると幸いです。  
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

今提示のサイトの通りに試してみた限りでは特にエラーは起こりませんでした。

Podファイルはプロジェクトフォルダの下、以下の３カ所に存在しました。

```
mbp:SOJ6621 user$ find . -name "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
./Pods/CorePlot/framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h
./Pods/Headers/Build/CorePlot/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h
./Pods/Headers/Public/CorePlot/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h
```

再確認すべき点（または情報を提示してほしい点）としては、

- プロジェクトファイル `xcodeproj` を閉じて、ワークスペースファイル `xcworkspace`で作業をしているか
- Bridging-Headerの配置場所
- コンパイラ設定で指定しているヘッダのパスが配置場所と合っているか

があると思います。
私の環境の画像を貼っておきますので参考にしてください。

- pod install結果

[image: pod install 結果]

- ヘッダファイルの位置と内容

[image: ヘッダファイルの位置と内容]

- コンパイラ設定 Objective C Bridging Header

[image: コンパイラ設定]

Comment: プロジェクトファイルの場所、ヘッダファイルの位置及び内容、コンパイラ設定全て同じですね…
ちなみにヘッダファイルの import 文のインデントは意図的なものでしょうか？
そこだけ私はインデント無しで記述しておりました。

Comment: @nsmkw インデントは意図したものではないです。それ以外では、何も考えずにファイルメニューからヘッダファイルを追加したらワークスペースファイルと同じ場所にヘッダが出来たので、Finderで移動したぐらいですかね。（プロジェクトツリーから移動させるとリンクが作成されてしまったのでそれは削除）